# How do I define the default XPath namespace in Saxon 9.5 EE in Java code?

Tags: xslt, saxon

How do I define the equivalent of the xpath-default-namespace, for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
```

in the following Java code snippet for Saxon EE 9.5?

```
public String transform(String request) {
    try {
        ProfessionalConfiguration config = new ProfessionalConfiguration();
        config.setExtensionElementNamespace("http://yeah.com", "com.MyFactory");
        config.registerExtensionFunction(new MyVariable());

        EnterpriseTransformerFactory factory = new EnterpriseTransformerFactory();
        factory.setConfiguration(config);

        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("text.xsl"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source input = new StreamSource(new File("test.xml"));
        StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(input, new StreamResult(result));

        return result.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, your code executes `text.xsl`, as long as that file has `xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` the XSLT processor should use that instruction. Is that not the case? Or do you want to run a stylesheet not having `xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` but want to define an XPath default element namespace nevertheless?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have got a XSL codebase where I cannot edit the XSLs. I want to run a stylesheet that does not have a having xpath-default-namespace set, but I still want to define xpath-default-namespace in the Java code that is used to execute that XSL.

Comment: I don't know whether that is possible with Saxon, let's wait and see what other have to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the default xpath namespace from your Java code, only from your XSLT code.

You say you can't edit the XSLT stylesheets but you can. They are XML documents and can be transformed, and you have a transformation language and transformation engine available to you. If there's no other way of solving this, transform the stylesheets before executing them.